# Error running PostgreSQL on Docker-io

Tags: postgresql, docker

When attempting to initialise the PostgreSQL database after installing on a Docker-io Fedora 19 container I get the following error:

```
bash-4.2# postgresql-setup initdb
Failed to get D-Bus connection: No connection to service manager.
failed to find PGDATA setting in postgresql.service
```

Looks like an environmental issue but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the command you are using to start the container? You might want to take a look at https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/2296